# Can I create SQL v10.0 databases in SQL R2 server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

Is there a way to create non-R2 databases in an R2 database server? I was hoping to do this in the compatibility options during the database creation, but only options are available for 2005 and 2000. Am I only stuck with installing the non-R2 SQL server to run side-by-side with my R2 database server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a way to create non-R2
>   databases in an R2 database server?

No. Once a database has been attached to a version of SQL server, it can never be re-attached to a previous version, even if the compatibility level stays the same.

> Am I only stuck with installing the
>   non-R2 SQL server to run side-by-side
>   with my R2 database server?

Yes.

Answer (score 2):

There is no SQL 2008 R2 compatibility mode, only the SQL 2008 compatibility mode.  This is because there are no syntax changes between SQL 2008 and SQL 2008 R2.